# material icon displays ugly

Tags: angular, angular-material, google-material-icons

I am trying to follow to use angular material icon for my angular data table.I follow this toturial for my angualar data table.  I see the same code displays a beautiful icon in his screen whereas I get an ugly icon on my screen,

here is my code.

datatable css file code.

```
.full-width-table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

datatable component html file code.

```
.....
.....
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>launch</mat-icon></button>
        <!-- <button mat-icon-button color="warn"><mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon></button> -->
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
....
....
```

my appModule file

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AppAsideModule,
    AppBreadcrumbModule.forRoot(),
    AppFooterModule,
    AppHeaderModule,
    AppSidebarModule,
    PerfectScrollbarModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    ChartsModule,
    SelectDropDownModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    CollapseModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatIconModule
],...
```

I have included this links in my index.html

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/favicon.ico">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

why I get an ugly icon but my toturial instructor get beautiful icon with the same code.
what things required to do in order to get the right one. you may see what I get via attached picture.

[image]

Comment: delete node module and install again.

Answer (score 2):

you must import `import MatButtonModule` on your `appModule`.

[Link to API reference](https://material.angular.io/components/button/api)

Answer (score 1):

**style.css or style.scss**

```
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
```

**Index.html**

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">
```

Import the above line and you can see the  beautiful icon

Comment: @import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";

Comment: I still get the same ugly one. altough I import it, reinstalled my angular material with selecting the deeppurple theme,...

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it now

Answer (score 0):

```
<button mat-mini-fab color="warn" aria-label="">
    <mat-icon>filter_list</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Ref Url - https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview